# Django Editing JsonResponse

Tags: json, python-3.x, django, jsonresponse

How I can add "points = " to this JsonResponse in Django?

My code look like this:

```
return JsonResponse(data=points, safe=False, json_dumps_params={'indent': 1})
```

Result :

> [
> {
> "x": 0,
> "y": 1
> },
> {
> "x": 0.315397047887207,
> "y": 0.694608645422627
> }
> ]

what I want to do :

> points=[
> {
> "x": 0,
> "y": 1
> },
> {
> "x": 0.315397047887207,
> "y": 0.694608645422627
> }
> ]

Comment: The return you want to have isn't a valid JSON. Do you really need a JSON response ?

Answer (score 0):

Look like you don't need JSON response. you need to pass a string in JSON.

for output like this : points=[ { "x": 0, "y": 1 }, { "x": 0.315397047887207, "y": 0.694608645422627 } ]

```
points_dict = {
    // value for points_key you can do some string concatenation for dynamic value
    'points_key': 'points=[ { "x": 0, "y": 1 }, { "x": 0.315397047887207, "y": 0.694608645422627 } ]'
}
return JsonResponse(data=points_dict, safe=False, json_dumps_params={'indent': 1})
```

Comment: Why would you return a string with JsonResponse rather than HttpResponse?

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before me, the response you want is not a JSON format.
As was suggested by a different answer, you can convert it into a string and send it like that:

```
pointsstr = f'points=[{points_dict}]'
return HttpResponse(pointsstr)
```

If you want to still use a JSON format then I suggest doing the following:

```
return JsonResponse(data={'points': points}, safe=False, json_dumps_params={'indent': 1})
```

This way your response would be:
`{"points": [{ "x": 0, "y": 1 }, { "x": 0.315397047887207, "y": 0.694608645422627 }]}`